# How to find the center point of a widget/object and use it in another function

Tags: python, object, tkinter, widget, coordinates

what I have here is work-in-progress of my Towers of Hanoi puzzle game. I've only been working on it a day or two and a problem I have here is the following: How am I able to snap an object to a specific position on the screen. What happens at the moment is the object snaps to a specific position depending on where your mouse touches the object.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    User_Input = input("How many disks?")
    global User_Input
    '''Illustrate how to drag items on a Tkinter canvas'''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=600, height=600)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # this data is used to keep track of an
        # item being dragged
        self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None, "score": 0}
        self._disk_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        self._pole1_data = {"x": 102, "y": 425}
        self._pole2_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        self._pole3_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0}

        # create a couple movable OBJECTS

        self._create_token((100, 550), "black")
        self._create_bases((100, 600), "orange")
        self._create_poles((145, 585), "blue")
        self.scores(0)

        # add bindings for clicking, dragging and releasing over
        # any object with the "token" tag
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.OnTokenButtonPress)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.OnTokenButtonRelease)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<B1-Motion>", self.OnTokenMotion)

    def scores(self, score):
        global setrep
        global score_set
        if score >= 0:
            self.score_set = Label(self.canvas, text = "Moves: " + str(score), width = 20, height = 5, bg = "black", fg = "white").place(relx = 0.76, rely = 0.82)


    def _create_poles(self, coord, color):
        (x,y) = coord
        for i in range(0, 3):
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-45, y-30, x-45, y-395, outline = color, fill = color)
            x += 150

    def _create_bases(self, coord, color):
        (x,y) = coord
        for i in range(0, 3):
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-45, y-25, x+45, y-45, outline = color, fill = color)
            x += 150



    def _create_token(self, coord, color):
        '''Create a token at the given coordinate in the given color'''
        (x,y) = coord
        for i in range(0, User_Input):

            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-45+(8*i), y-25, x+45, y-45, outline=color, fill=color, tags="token")
            y -= 50
            x -= 4.5

    def OnTokenButtonPress(self, event):
        '''Being drag of an object'''
        # record the item and its location
        self._drag_data["item"] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

    def OnTokenButtonRelease(self, event):
        '''End drag of an object'''
        # reset the drag information
        self._drag_data["x"] = 0
        self._drag_data["y"] = 0
        self._drag_data["score"] += 1
        self.scores(self._drag_data["score"])
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], self._pole1_data["x"]-event.x, self._pole1_data["y"]-event.y)
        print event.x, event.y
        self._drag_data["item"] = None


    def OnTokenMotion(self, event):
        '''Handle dragging of an object'''
        # compute how much this object has moved
        delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
        delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        # record the new position
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

I advise just using 1 or 2 disks for testing as it may get confusing otherwise.

The main part you wan to be looking at is in **def TokenButtonRelease(self, event)** and where it states **self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], self._pole1_data["x"]-event.x, self._pole1_data["y"]-event.y)**

The problem is the "-event.x" and "-event.y", as I really want to be minus'ing the centre point of the object. So my main question is how do I find this and how do I state that I want this to be the value that has to be taken away. You will notice that the object snaps to a certain position, but if you grab the object at different points, it will obviously snap to a slightly different point.

Comment: There are some serious problems with this code. First, you're using `global` in a class, which is generally useless, and you're using it after the first assignment, which prints a warning and has undefined behavior, and you're inputting its value at class definition time, which is weird. You probably wanted to put this either outside the class entirely, or inside the `__init__` method (in which case it should be storing in an attribute, not a global).

Comment: Okay, I'm really new to classes and object-oriented coding, I'll change it around a bit, cheers

Comment: Meanwhile, it sounds like what you really want to do is snap the position to whichever pole it's nearest to? If so, what is `_pole1_data["x"] - event.x` supposed to be giving you?

Comment: _pole1_data["x"] - event.x gives me the position of the location of the pole minus the position of the mouse pointer. This in term gives me the location of a section on the first pole

Comment: self._pole1_data["x"] gives me the x-coordinates of a point on the first pole. I minus the coordinates of the mouse away from this to place the pointer on the pole. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep track of the top left corner in a dictionary or some container.  You can then move the top left corner to any position you want, and update the dictionary of course.  This program uses tag_bind to tell when the mouse enters the rectangle as a simple demonstration of identifying the position, but of course you can use a button release, etc. as well.

```
try
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

from functools import partial

class SampleApp():
    '''Illustrate how to drag items on a Tkinter canvas'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_input=0
        self.get_input()

        self.top=tk.Tk()
        self.create_canvas()
        self.x=20
        self.y=100
        self.rectangle_dict={}
        for ctr in range(0, self.user_input):
            self.create_rectangle(ctr)
        self.top.mainloop()

    def create_canvas(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=600, height=600)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def create_rectangle(self, ctr):
        colors=["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "yellow"]
        rc = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y,.
                           self.x+25, self.y+50, outline='white',
                           fill=colors[ctr])
        ## call the function, "func1", and send the value
        ## in ctr to it when the mouse enters
        ## this rectangle, i.e. different memory
        ## address/rectangle for "rc" for each 
        ## function call
        self.canvas.tag_bind(rc, "<Enter>",
                             partial(self.func1, ctr))
        self.rectangle_dict[ctr]=[self.x, self.y]
        self.x += 75
        self.y += 100

    def func1(self, ctr, event):
        """ "bind" sends a Tkinter event which must
            be caught even though it is not used
        """
        print "Enter called for rectangle number", ctr
        print "top left corner is %d, %d" % (self.rectangle_dict[ctr][0],
                                                self.rectangle_dict[ctr][1])

    def get_input(self):
        """ allow for 1 to 5 rectangles to be created
        """
        while self.user_input not in range(1, 6):
            self.user_input = raw_input("How many disks? ")
            if self.user_input.isdigit():
                self.user_input=int(self.user_input)
        print "%d disks will be created" % (self.user_input)

SA=SampleApp()
```

Comment: Thank-you for taking the time to work on this for me. I do appreciate it, I will take some time to interpret this code and implement different parts into my code and adjust it where necessary. My new code will be pasted when completed. Cheers Joe.